# regex to produce duplicate string with modification

Tags: regex, solr

I have string as "abc xyz pqr pyz" i want to make it like "abc xyz pqr pyz abcxyzpqrpyz". so basically take same string and duplicate it without spaces. I have to achieve this in solr "solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory".
One workout is to introduce intermediate field and use copy field. but i don't want to use intermediate field due to space constraints.
I am looking for some like
`(([a-z]+)\s([a-z]+)\s([a-z]+)\s([a-z]+))` with replacement of `\1 \2\3\4\5`. this works for exactly 4 words in string but i am looking for something that will work for any number of words.

Comment: what is maximum length of input string?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about solr but why you don't remove spaces as following :

```
<filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="(\s+)" replacement="" replace="all" />
```

and then concat original string by this result

Comment: it does not work that way in solr. i need one regex with replacement that will do the trick.